# tkinter -How to enable a button state to 'normal' from disabled when user starts typing inside entry field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter to build a GUI. I have two field, One Entry field for accepting user input and other is submit button. My intention is when the GUI invokes Submit button should be in disabled state, which I achieved by setting state of the button as 'disabled'.

```
self.submit = ttk.Button(self, text='Submit', state = 'disabled')
```

So when user starts typing in the entry field, then Submit button state should be changed to 'normal'. Written below function :

```
def enable_responseButton(self):

        self.user_input.bind("<Key>",self.respond.config(state='normal',command = self.get_response))
```

And pass the function as command in Entry field as below:

```
self.input = ttk.Entry(self,state = "normal",command = self.enable_responseButton)
```

However when I ran my script, GUI opens up and Submit button state is by default enabled even if user did not enter any value. 
Is there any way I need to wait for user input and until then button will be in disabled state ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Variable class objects in sync with entry's text, the button is disabled as long as the entry is empty, and enabled when not in the example below:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def toggle_state(*_):
    if entry.var.get():
        button['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        button['state'] = 'disabled'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.var = tk.StringVar()
    entry['textvariable'] = entry.var
    entry.var.trace_add('write', toggle_state)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Button", state='disabled')
    entry.pack()
    button.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```