# Creating/destroying widgets with tkinter depending on a traced variable

Tags: python, tkinter, trace

I would like to create a button depending on the current status of an entry widget: If there is something written there, the button should be created, but if it is cleared again, the button should be destroyed again.

In the following code I achieved something 'similar':

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

check = StringVar()

def create(*args):
    if check.get() != '':
        grid_014 = Button(root, width=40, text='something changed', bd=5)
    else:
        grid_014 = Label(root, width=40, text='', bd=5)

    grid_014.grid(column=1, row=2)

grid_entry = Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=check)
grid_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

check.trace('w', create)

root.mainloop()
```

But then I realized, not quite. Because, as far as I understand, what I am doing is replacing the button widget with the label widget and vice versa, always on top of each other. This is visible, because the boundary of the button widget does not vanish. As far as I understand, this is also creating a memory leak.

My question now is, what would be the best way of 'clearing' the previous widget if a change in the entry widget causes a change in the if condition?

The reason behind this is, that I want to give the user of the program possibilities to interact with certain parts of it, only if certain conditions are met before, say a 'save' button would only appear, after a file name is written, things like this.

For instance, rather than destroying a widget greying it out, using a traced 
variable, could be an alternative. (A working solution for this is given by the link of Nae, thanks (!), using the 'normal' and 'disabled' state of a button; However, I would like to see other suggestions, too, which would comment on the possibility of clearing widgets, too, because in the general case, as given in the above code, it would not be the same widget in the if condition, thus one would not be able to use 'normal'/'disabled' state of the same widget).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkinter -How to enable a button state to 'normal' from disabled when user starts typing inside entry field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988799/tkinter-how-to-enable-a-button-state-to-normal-from-disabled-when-user-starts)

Answer (score 1):

Your realizations are correct AFAIK. The best way I can think of doing exactly what you want as opposed to an alternative would be to simply destroying the widget if it exists before creating a new one.

Add another `if` that `destroy`s the `grid_014`, if it exists such as:

```
if grid_014:
    grid_014.destroy()
if check.get() != '':
    grid_014 = Button(root, width=40, text='something changed', bd=5)
else:
    grid_014 = Label(root, width=40, text='', bd=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `entry` widget is empty then you `disabled` it if the `entry` is not empty then is should be active .

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()

check = StringVar()

def create(*args):
    if check.get() != '':
        grid_014 = Button(root, width=40, text='something changed', bd=5)
    elif len(check.get())==0:
        grid_014 = Button(root, width=40, state="disabled")
    else:
        grid_014 = Label(root, width=40, text='', bd=5)

    grid_014.grid(column=1, row=2)

grid_entry = Entry(root, width=40, textvariable=check)
grid_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

check.trace('w', create)

root.mainloop()
```